# NSMutableArray in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am just stuck here, I cannot figure it out what I am doing wrong here. I am pretty new to objective c. In my application I am using a `UITableView` and `NSMutableArray` to parse data from RSS feed. I want to refresh the whole table with new data when user click on the segment control in the tableview. I have added the segment control in table header section and it works fine with changing the value when segment index changed.

The problem is now when I click on the segment control it adds the new rows in the tableview instead of refreshing the whole table. Here is the code:

```
- (void)addEarthquakesToList:(NSArray *)earthquakes
    {
    //NSInteger startingRow = [self.earthquakeList count];
    NSInteger earthquakeCount = [earthquakes count];
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:earthquakeCount];
    NSLog(@"%d",earthquakeCount);

    for (NSInteger row = 0; row < (earthquakeCount); row++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
        [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    [self.earthquakeList addObjectsFromArray:earthquakes];
    [self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                           withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

I have tried many other things like `[self.tableView reloadData];`
I have also tried the following to remove all objects from the array and remove rows from table but it does not display correct number of rows:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [self.earthquakeList count]; i++)
    {
        [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }

    //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    //[self.tableView endUpdates];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

And these are my tableView DataSource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // The number of rows is equal to the number of earthquakes in the array.
    return [self.earthquakeList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kEarthquakeCellID = @"EarthquakeCellID";
    citsTableViewCell *cell = (citsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kEarthquakeCellID];

    //Get the specific earthquake for this row.
    citsFuelFinder *earthquake = (self.earthquakeList)[indexPath.row];
    [cell configureWithEarthquake:earthquake];
    return cell;
}
```

---

In fact when try to include the following in the segment control:

```
- (void)segmentedControlHasChangedValue
{
    int product;
    product = fuelType.selectedSegmentIndex;

    switch (product)
    {
        case 0:
            productName=1;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case 1:
            productName=2;
            //[self.earthquakeList removeLastObject];
            if (![self.earthquakeList count])
            {
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            }
            else
            {
                NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [self.earthquakeList count]; i++)
                {
                    [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i
                                                                     inSection:0]];
                }
                //[self.tableView beginUpdates];
                //[self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
                [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete
                                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                //[self.tableView endUpdates];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                //[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
            }
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case 2:
            productName=4;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case 3:
            productName=5;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (15) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (15), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted,
>   15 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2e332e83 0x3868f6c7 0x2e332d55 0x2ecdb0af 0x30c8a34d 0x30cb083f 0x6d2d9 0x30aebda3 0x30aebd3f
>   0x30aebd13 0x30ad7743 0x30bf7c59 0x30bf7a27 0x30cbca25 0x30aaf1a1
>   0x30ae69fd 0x30ae63ab 0x30abbd79 0x30aba569 0x2e2fdf1f 0x2e2fd3e7
>   0x2e2fbbd7 0x2e266471 0x2e266253 0x32fa02eb 0x30b1b845 0x6948d
>   0x38b88ab7)

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: So what you're trying to do is always have the table display the data in `self.earthquakeList`, and clear out said data whenever an update occurs? Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: yes, thats exactly right. Thanks Carl

Comment: there is no need to insert new rows. You can change the datasource(earthquakeList) and reload tableview

Comment: sorry i'm not sure what you mean. could you please elaborate a bit more ...

Comment: Why you update the indexpaths? Directly set source array and call [self.tableview reloadData];

Comment: kindly edit your post to include these 2 methods **-numberOfRowsInSection** && **-cellForRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: I have added those methods now.Thanks

Comment: aren't you getting your data by parsing some RSS feed? why are you using the CoreLocation framework? why put all that code in the **-didUpdateToLocation** delegate? do you ever **stopUpdatingLocation**?

Answer (score 0):

Update the source array of tableview, No need to insert new rows.

```
[self.earthquakeList addObjectsFromArray:earthquakes];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add elements to the data source array, no. of rows in the table view will update automatically. You don't need to insert rows. Just insert elements. Implement your method as:

```
- (void)addEarthquakesToList:(NSArray *)earthquakes 
{
   [self.earthquakeList addObjectsFromArray:earthquakes];
   [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

erm, instead of

```
[self.tableView  insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

try

```
[self.tableView  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

---

anyways.... your code snippets are still insufficient, for me atleast, to locate your problem.

But since you said:
`I want to refresh the whole table with new data when user click on the segment control in the tableview.`

If i had to make a segmented tableView with 4 segments that displays different data for different segments, i'd do this:

NOTE: this is a basic example. it doesn't adhere to your specific code but should give you an idea to drop the logic of playing with indexPaths or that manual adding/removing objects from the array and instead use the `tableView reloadData` appropriately.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //declare NSArray *arrFirst, *arrSecond, *arrThird, *arrFourth, *arrSelected
    //in the .h file

    arrFirst = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"eins",@"zwei",@"drei",@"vier",@"fünf",@"sechs", nil];
    arrSecond = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three",@"four",@"five",@"six",@"seven",@"eigth",@"nine", nil];
    arrThird = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"uno",@"dos",@"tres",@"cuatro",@"cinco", nil];
    arrFourth = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ek",@"do",@"teen",@"chaar",@"paach",@"che",@"saat", nil];

    arrSelected = arrFirst;
}
```

---

```
- (IBAction)mySegmentsAct:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            arrSelected = arrFirst;
            break;
        case 1:
            arrSelected = arrSecond;
            break;
        case 2:
            arrSelected = arrThird;
            break;
        case 3:
            arrSelected = arrFourth;
            break;
        default:
            arrSelected = nil;
            break;
    }

    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

---

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrSelected count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = (arrSelected)[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I could also do this using a single array as well, by flushing the old array contents first:
`arrSelected = nil`
and then put the new elements in this array (from some source using some logic)
and finally:
`myTableView reloadData`.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried your first suggestion but didn't work, it crashes with wrong row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you selected the second segment and the crash came out? 
So the following codes cause the error.

```
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete
                                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

When you use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths or insertRowAtIndexPaths, you must insure the length of the datasource matches the current row of tableView.
For example: your tableView already has 10 rows, now you need to delete 2 rows, you should remove 2 data objects from your datasource array first, then call deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: I have tried -(void)clearData{
    
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        
        NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
            NSLog(@"Deleted: %d",i);
        }
    
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        
}

Comment: [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects]; must run before deleteRows~~

Answer (score 0):

Try these replacements, and give us some feedback later (specially if any NSAssert "crashed" your app):

```
- (void)addEarthquakesToList:(NSArray *)earthquakes
{
    // data checking
    NSAssert(self.earthQuakeList != nil, @"earthQuakeList cannot be nil!");
    NSAssert(self.tableView != nil, @"tableView cannot be nil!");
    NSAssert(earthquakes != nil, @"earthquakes cannot be nil!");

    // relevant implementation
    [self.earthquakeList addObjectsFromArray:earthquakes];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)segmentedControlHasChangedValue
{
    // data checking
    NSAssert(self.earthQuakeList != nil, @"earthQuakeList cannot be nil!");
    NSAssert(self.tableView != nil, @"tableView cannot be nil!");
    NSAssert(fuelType != nil, @"fuelType cannot be nil!");
    NSAssert(locationManager != nil, @"locationManager cannot be nil!");

    // relevant implementation
    switch (fuelType.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            productName=1; // what is this?
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case 1:
            productName=2;
            [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        case 2:
            productName=4;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;
        case 3:
            productName=5;
            [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData]; // if you want to change the data whenever the user changes the UISegmentedControl to any new value, leave this here.
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // data checking
    NSAssert(self.earthQuakeList != nil, @"earthQuakeList cannot be nil!");
    NSAssert(self.tableView != nil, @"tableView cannot be nil!");

    // relevant implementation
    [self.earthquakeList removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```